# Using newer version of api python client in google app engine SDK

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api-python-client

I'm playing with Google App Engine python SDK and now I run into a problem:

The version of My App Engine SDK is 1.7.5, which contains a version 1.0beta google api python client. However myproject needs to have reference to version 1.1 of google api python client. I tried almost everything but I couldn't find a solution. Does any one know how can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version packaged with the SDK is not the version your project will use. That version is only used for the SDK and is not even available in production App Engine applications.

As the `google-api-python-client` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation#appengine) says:

> Because [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) requires that all of the source files
>   for a library must be present in your App Engine project, there is a
>   special installation procedure for App Engine. To install the library
>   and all of its dependencies in an App Engine project, download the
>   file named `google-api-python-client-gae-N.M.zip` from the [list of
>   downloads](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/downloads/list), where `N.M` is the version number of the latest
>   release. Unzip that file into your project. For example:
>
> `$ cd myproject` 
>   `$ unzip google-api-python-client-gae-1.0.zip`

Comment: Why then would the App Engine SDK package an apparently useless version of the Google Api client?

Comment: It's not useless, it's stable enough for what the SDK uses it for. It isn't included for direct use by your code and no where is it documented as such.